# Links from historical election pages point to current resources

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, election

On election pages, there is a short section with links to additional resources. As an example, here is the relevant part for the [2013 Stack Overflow moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4):

[image: screenshet of the link section from the 2013 SO moderator election]

Apparently, however, the content for that section is shared among all past and present elections for a site. Therefore, the *Election chat room* and *The candidates answer your questions* links lead to the relevant pages for the latest election (in the case of Stack Overflow, the [fall 2015 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/7)); the overview linked from *More information about the candidates* also seems to provide information only about the latest election. The *Meta* link is, of course, timeless.

This is not limited to Stack Overflow, although some sites appear to omit this section altogether (e.g. [DBA SE has it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/1), [Physics SE not](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/2)).

Ideally, the links should lead to the resources relevant for each election. If this is not possible (or worth the effort), the section shouldn’t be displayed at all.